# Is installing compiler on a virtual pc vs desktop more secure?

Tags: security, virtual-machine

My supervisor is pushing developers to install any compiler (Visual studio etc) on a virtual machine  vs desktop. His argument is, it is more secure to put compiler on virtual in case desktops are hacked. But if i can access virtual machine from my desktop then hacker can too. I am just trying to understand why it is more secure to put compiler on virtual. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If virtual machine is hosted in the cloud(public/private/internal) then probably somebody else is managing security in the cloud. That case probably it is almost certain that it will provide more security then bare desktop.

However we are relying on the somebody.

If your VM is running on desktop hypervisor, then I would prefer doing all work on the VM. In hacking scenario, I would still have my desktop, while VM may be gone.

I have seen something similar when Ransomware attack happened, all windows desktop were gone including local filesystem/vms, but only VM running Windows were affected, and hypervisor and local filesystem were all good if running non-windows host os.

Not sure if it answer your question, but putting my perspective on what I have seen so far in the industry.

Comment: If my desktop is compromised  how does having compiler on a VM helps?

Comment: I don't think it helps.